# Does Facebook page token data access expiry apply to profiles read from messages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook’s [data access expiry documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data/) details the new distinction between authentication and data access.

The permissions listed as not expiring do not include the default profile read permission.

Currently I’m making API calls to fetch the [messages edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/conversation/messages) of a conversation thread.
This requires the `read_page_mailboxes` permission which my page access token has and according to the documentation will not expire.
Messages [include a `from` field](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/message) which contains a subset of a user profile. Will data access to this field continue to work after a 90 day expiry as accessing the data for the message appears to only need the `read_page_mailboxes` permission?

From my understanding the profile read permission is not part of this API call and only applies to the profile of the user that authenticates with the app and not the profiles read from messages to a page’s mailbox.
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. Everything else would not make much sense, I think. (Not every user that messages a page, will have logged into your specific app before anyway. But your app needs access to this most basic profile info do to its job and manage the page’s messages to begin with … so it would not make sense, if there was any connection between the two permissions in the first place.)